# How can I create a list with all child's name? android studio - firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[my firebase code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNiDn.png)
[my android studio codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojvlg.png)

How can I create a list  with all child's name?
For example in this case ["lupo", "soccer_class"]
What should I write inside addValueEventListener?

Comment: Please share your database structure.

Comment: Please replace the pictures of text with the actual code and JSON as text. For the database, you can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `classi` is a direct child of Firebase root, to achieve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("classi");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.getKey();
            list.add(name);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
lupo
soccer_class
```